# Looping through a datatable using JQuery

Tags: jquery, datatable

[enter image description here][1]Hi I'm very new to Javascript, when I click a button I want to loop through my datatable looking for checkbox values of true, when a true value is found I want to pass the Id from the row and text from an input field to a method in my controller as parameters.

I've been trying something like this (Javascript Code below) but I just can't get it working and I have no idea if my loop function is running. Could someone please help me figure this out?

**HTML for button**

```
<form method="post" style="margin-bottom: 41px">
    <input class="btn btn-primary text-warning" value="Extend Selected Licenses" type="submit" onclick="loopGrid" id="btnExtendSelectedLicense"></input>
    <input class="form-control" id="NumberOfDaysExtended" type="number" style="height: 30px; width: 100px; margin-left: 216px; margin-top: -41px">
</form>
```

**HTML for checkbox**

```
<td> 
    <input class="form-check-input bg-light" id="SelectedLicenses" type="checkbox">
</td>
```

**JQuery script for loop function**

```
function loopGrid {
    var table = document.getElementById("CustomerLicensingTable");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            SelectedLicenses == true
            //call method
            console.log("found a true value")
        } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

```js
 
    function loopGrid() {
        var $table = $("#CustomerLicensingTable tr");
        $table.each(function(){
           var $check = $($(this).find(".form-check-input"));
           if($check.is(':checked')){
              alert('Checked Id = ' + $check.attr("id"));
              $(this).show();
           } else {
             console.log('Not checked');
              $(this).hide();
           }
        });
    }
    $(document).on("click", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       loopGrid();
       //$("#license-form").submit();
       // OR use Ajax 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" style="margin-bottom: 41px" id="license-form">
    <input class="btn btn-primary text-warning" value="Extend Selected Licenses" type="button" id="btnExtendSelectedLicense"></input>
    <input class="form-control" id="NumberOfDaysExtended" type="number" style="height: 30px; width: 100px; margin-left: 216px; margin-top: -41px">
</form>

<table id="CustomerLicensingTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-check-input bg-light" type="checkbox" id="check1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-check-input bg-light" type="checkbox" id="check2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-check-input bg-light" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="check3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-check-input bg-light" type="checkbox" id="check4">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your response. I'm trying to get your sample working but the console.log is not logging anything, I have removed the "$(document).on("click", function(e){" section as it was causing the grid to respond in a weird way. I dont know how to else to check if the loop is working, is there a way to get the Id from the selected row and pass that to a method in the controller ?
Many thanks

Comment: @SheUsesVaseline check my update I have added an alert to get the selected checkbox id

Comment: Hi thank you

I see that it fires whenever the checkbox is checked but what I'm trying to do is select multiple rows using the checkbox and then click the Extend Licenses button which will then loop through the grid and pass the @item.Id from the row that is checked a method in my controller as a parameter.

Many thanks again.